# Kibana to plot Value over time line chart based on a filter on other index

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, kibana, linechart, kibana-4

> I have two indices: `data_props and ch_groups`.
>
> data_props contains: `id, name`.
>
> ch_groups contains: `variable, value and timestamp`.

This data has been imported into ElasticSearch from MySQL TimeSeries Datasource.
In MySQL, `ch_groups.variable` was a foreign key referring to `data_props.id`

***My Requirement is:***

For a particular `data_props.id`, plot `ch_groups.value (Y-Axis)` over `ch_groups.timestamp (X-Axis)` on a line chart.

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: What library or tool do you use to draw the line chart? Are you doing it with some database visualization tools? Or do you want a library drawn in the front-end using JavaScript? Could you share some code?

Comment: Hi FelisCatus, Thanks for the reply. I'm using Kibana to create these Visualisations. As Kibana allows only aggregations on the Y-Axis, i'm unable to plot a value over Time Line chart.